# How to make `learnr` tutorials appear in a certain order?

Tags: r, sorting, package, learnr

When authoring an R package with `learnr` tutorials, is there a way to make them appear in an order that is not alphabetical, but user defined?

See the following example: The `hello` tutorial is most basic and should appear first. But the tutorials are alphabetically sorted by their name.

```r
learnr::available_tutorials("learnr")

Available tutorials:
* learnr
  - ex-data-basics    : "Data basics"
  - ex-data-filter    : "Filter observations"
  - ex-data-mutate    : "Create new variables"
  - ex-data-summarise : "Summarise Tables"
  - ex-setup-r        : "Set Up"
  - hello             : "Hello, Tutorial!"
  - polyglot          : "Multi-language exercises"
  - quiz_question     : "Tutorial Quiz Questions in `learnr`"
  - setup-chunks      : "Chained setup chunks"
  - slidy             : "Slidy demo"
  - sql-exercise      : "Interactive SQL Exercises"
```

I am looking for an option, like `swirl`s MANIFEST file, which specifies the order.
Only if there is no such option I would resort to renaming the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to change the order unless you change the names. The code for `learnr` finds tutorials by running [list.dirs on the package folder](https://github.com/rstudio/learnr/blob/7f26e8431eaedde64076be5fbd24514816915c14/R/available_tutorials.R#L71) And according to the `?list.dirs` help page "the files are sorted in alphabetical order, on the full path if full.names = TRUE." There's no current way to specify a manifest. You'd have to request a new feature from the package authors.